# How create a Directory WHIT PHP and HTML whit a Button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, directory

Hello i have a problem... Suppose that i have a table whit two textBox and one button.. when i click the button i must read the value of a textBox and create a directory in a specific path and the directory must be named like the value that i read on the TextBox

I've tryed this code but it dosn't work :(

file = directory.php

```html
<?php


$idCantiere = $_POST["idCantiere"];
$codiceCommessa = $_POST["codiceCommessa"];
echo("Registrazione avvenuta");

chdir("../inserimento");
opendir(".");
mkdir("../inserimento/prova/".$idCantiere);

?>
```

file prova.html

```html
<table method="POST" action="directory.php">
<tr>
           <td bgcolor="#B2E5FB">Cantiere</td>
           <td colspan="11">&nbsp;<input type="text" id="idCantiere"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td bgcolor="#B2E5FB">Codice Commessa</td>
           <td colspan="11">&nbsp;<input type="text" id="codiceCommessa"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td><button name="insAffidatario" type="submit" onclick="directory.php">Inserisci Affidatario</button></td></tr>
         </table>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions should be asked in english on the main Stack Overflow

Comment: Sorry it's my first post .. now it's in english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code and it is a specific one; is that you used `<table></table>` for what should be a form, it should be `<form></form>`.

Then you used ID's instead of name attributes. You need to add `name="idCantiere"` and `name="codiceCommessa"` to their respective inputs.

You may also want to remove `onclick="directory.php"` here. The "action" already takes care of that.

Side note: Place your table inside the form and not outside. `<form>` cannot be made child of `<table>`.

Also make sure that the paths (and folders) correspond and that they are writeable with proper group/user permissions.

Error reporting will be of help also.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

and set to catch and display.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but i can't understand to fix this part : 
"Also make sure that the paths (and folders) correspond and that they are writeable with proper group/user permissions"
Can you help me ? How i can see if i have the permission for read/write? How i can add?

Comment: @NarcosZTK_10 Meaning that the path `../folder` etc. already exist and that they can be written inside it/them. If you get an error that they cannot be created, then you will need to `chmod` them, given that you're on a Linux/Unix operating system. Otherwise, you would need to use the Windows equivalent but I don't think you're on a Windows, right?

Comment: @NarcosZTK_10 welcome, glad to have been of help. You can mark the question as solved if you want. This is done on a voluntary basis. However, in doing that, it informs everyone and the system that a solution was found and will mark it as such. *Benvenuto a Stack Overflow!* Si, I speak the language fairly well :-)

Comment: Can you help me here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684755/how-create-a-tree-directory-structure :(